# DoubleClick for Publishers Out-Of-Page Slot with Size Mapping for Responsive sites

Tags: javascript, responsive, google-dfp

Does anyone know how to target an out of page ad slot with the Google sizeMapping object for serving responsive ads?

I've tried using "Out-of-page" as the size, but it's not working.

```
var outOfPageMapping = googletag.sizeMapping().addSize(['out-of-page']).
    addSize([0, 0], ['Out-of-page']).
    addSize([1000, 0], []).
    build();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after I refined my google search to include "out-of-page", in quotes, I was able to find a Google Group for DFP with the answer!

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dfp/OqW_uLU9TJ0

Thanks to Nico Hiort af Ornas, and Rajkumar of Google Support!

Here is Rajkumar's response to Nico's inquiry. I tested, it works:

> I read through the post and yes, DFP supports responsive design for
> out-of-page ad units and you can call defineSizeMapping() function on
> defineOutOfPageSlot(). You will just need to add the size [1, 1] to
> the sizeMapping function. Here is a sample design:
>
> ```
>  var sizeMapping = googletag.sizeMapping().
>        addSize([0, 0], []).
>        addSize([1210, 0], [1, 1]).
>        build();
>
>
>  googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('...','...').defineSizeMapping(sizeMapping).addService(googletag.pubads());
> ```

Comment: var mapMastcatfish = googletag.sizeMapping().
                addSize([0, 0], [[970, 90], [728, 90], [970, 250]]).
                addSize([1210, 0], [1, 1]).
                build();

Comment: googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/10176910/CatFishHead','catfish_ad').defineSizeMapping(mapMastcatfish).addService(googletag.pubads());

Comment: Are you refreshing the page after you change the browser window size?